# Split-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null in Constructor

Tags: powershell, class, scripting

Im trying to get a hold on classes in PowerShell at the moment. 
I'm trying to running the following code:

```
class myClass{
    [String] $path

    myClass(){
        $this.path = Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
    }
}

$a = [myClass]::new()
#$a.tokenpath
#Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
```

But I get the following error:

```
Split-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
```

I dont get the error if I run the same line of code outside of the class.
Does anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$MyInvocation.MyCommand` does not seem to work inside classes. However `$psscriptroot` works and does the same as `Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition`

updated code:

```
class myClass{
    [String] $path

    myClass(){
        $this.path = $PSScriptRoot
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats very handy. Thank you for your answer :)

Comment: Is is possible to use a classes methods within the classes constructor in powershell. I'm trying to do something along the line of:

   `class myClass{

        [Void] myMethod(){
            Write-Host "Hello World!"
        }

        myClass(){
            [myClass]::myMethod()
        }
    }

    $test = [myClass]::new()
`
But Im getting the following error:
   
    Method invocation failed because [myClass] does not contain a method named 'myMethod'.

Comment: the method call would be $this.myMethod() instead of [myclass]::myMethod()

Comment: $MyInvocation.MyCommand also doesn't work inside of functions